# Responsive Buttons

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a simple responsive template, but unfortunately when I "shrink" the page from inspect the buttons don't go with the flow.

Here's my code:

```css
.w3container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 750px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3container">
  <button class="btn1">btn1</button>
  <button class="btn2">btn2</button>
  <button class="btn3">btn3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: tryna make my webpage responsive, so when you click "inspect" on your web browser, there's a "phone screen" button, so you'd see how does your web page looks on a smartphone. when i do that my buttons just don't move (shrink),they stay "behind" the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
button {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Or if you want the buttons full width

```
button {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: didn't seem work, i actually added {float:right;}   , it surprisingly shrinks, but as i shrink the page, buttons disappear one-by-one. seems like they're hiding behind some elements

Comment: Remove the position relative and left from the container, that's probably forcing them off the page when your screen is less than 750 pixels in width